# simple fade in fade out misfunction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very dumb problem I am sure, but it's keeping me busy for too long know without being able to solve it.

I'm trying to make only one page with hidden divs that will appear on top of the main div when a button is clicked. I have no problem doing so. The problem appears when I try to implement a fade in and fade out effect at the same time on those two divs.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function goin() {
    $("#container").fadeOut(1000, 0);
}

function goin1() {
    $("#hidden").fadeIn(1500);
}

function goback() {
    $("#hidden").fadeOut(1000, 0);

}

function goback1() {
    $("#container").fadeIn(1000);
}

showNextQuote();

$("#playbtn").click(function(){
    $.when(goin()).then(goin1());
});

$("#backbtn").click(function(){
    $.when(goback()).then(goback1());
});
})();
```

html:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="particles-js">
 </div>
<div class="mainhover">
  <button id="playbtn"></button>
  <footer id="footer">
    <p>&copy; 2016 whatapage.ch</p>
  </footer>
</div>
</div>

<div id="hidden">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <button id="backbtn">press to fad in again</button>
</div>
```

the div #hidden just appears and disappears without the fade in fade out effect. Any clue on what is happening here?

Comment: Have you tried this `$("#hidden").fadeIn('slow');`?

Comment: @KANAYOAUSTINKANE I can try, but it will not make a lot of difference since 1500 is setting the time in millisecond rather than just putting slow or fast.

Comment: Can you include your html too please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I got a working solution:

I placed #hidden in the #container div. All of a sudden everything worked out.